# datatables jquery supply dynamic array index value on "sClass"

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Given the following code:

```
var aDataSet = [
    ['1', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['2', 'Fish','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['3', 'Pony','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaData": aDataSet,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Engine" },
        { "sTitle": "Browser" },
        { "sTitle": "Platform" },
        { "sTitle": "Version", "sClass": "customCSS-" +aDataSet['id']['Version']  }, 
        { "sTitle": "Grade", "sClass": "center" }
    ]
} );
```

I would like to be able to look up the current being processed `aDataSet` element and get its `Version` information back so that I can do a string concatenation within the context of `aoColumns` styling.  The above does not perform any styling.  This modification:

```
    { "sTitle": "Version", "sClass": "customCSS-" +aDataSet[0]['Version']  }
```

makes everything match the zeroth index (clearly), but I would expect I could somehow force that lookup.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I honestly don't think you are worried about the `Version` value in and of itself because that's just the datatables standard dummy data, so I took the liberty of not using that as part of the concatenation of the `css` class name. The `Version` value contains dots, and those will make a mess of the css. Then bearing that in mind, and assuming I understand what you are trying to do, here's one way to go about the task, as shown on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/onelev/2/edit

The primary point here is the use of **[fnRowCallback](http://www.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback)** to generate
the dynamic class name on the table cell.

**CSS** for styling custom cell colors

```
.customCSS-Trident, table.dataTable tr.even td.customCSS-Trident.sorting_1, table.dataTable tr.odd td.customCSS-Trident.sorting_1 { background-color: blue; color: #fff; }
.customCSS-Fish, table.dataTable tr.even td.customCSS-Fish.sorting_1, table.dataTable tr.odd td.customCSS-Fish.sorting_1 { background-color: green; color: #fff; }
.customCSS-Pony, table.dataTable tr.even td.customCSS-Pony.sorting_1, table.dataTable tr.odd td.customCSS-Pony.sorting_1 { background-color: brown; color: yellow; }
.customCSS-Cabbage, table.dataTable tr.even td.customCSS-Cabbage.sorting_1, table.dataTable tr.odd td.customCSS-Cabbage.sorting_1 { background-color: pink; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $(document).ready( function() {
     var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
       "aaData": aDataSet,
       "aoColumnDefs": [ 
         {  "aTargets": [ 0 ], 
            "sTitle": "#" 
         },
         {  "aTargets": [ 1 ], 
            "sTitle": "Engine" 
         },
        { "aTargets": [ 2 ], 
           "sTitle": "Browser" 
        },
        { "aTargets": [ 3 ], 
         "sTitle": "Platform" 
        },
         { "aTargets": [ 4 ],
          "sTitle": "Version"
        },      
        { "aTargets": [ 5 ], 
          "sTitle": "Grade", 
          "sClass": "center" 
         }
       ], 
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
          $('td:eq(4)', nRow).addClass("customCSS-" + aData[1]);    
            return nRow;
        },
     });
   } );
```

**HTML**

```
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Addendum**
DataTables dynamically generates the `sorting_1` class when you sort one particular column. If you have sophisticated users who hold the shift key and then click another column header, then datatables generates another class called `sorting_2`, and so on. While the chances of having a user sort by multiple columns is likely quite low, the cases could be handled by adding additional `css` rules for those extra cases.

Comment: that is delightful.  I am going to get that integrated into my code and if successful will accept your answer.  Have you considered giving this example to the project?  Because according to everything I have ever seen I had to embed this content inside of an individual DIV